# How to configure FTPs on AWS EC2 with windows instance

Tags: windows, iis, amazon-ec2, ftp, ftps

How to configure FTPs on AWS EC2 with windows instance?

Comment: *"But the issue is unable to access FTPs using filezila."* - That's hardly enough information for us to provide you with any help. Post error message, log file, anything. And your question is off-topic here anyway, please move it to [su] (delete here, re-post there) - But provide a way more information when re-posting, otherwise do not even bother posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your IIS configuration is correct, you should also edit the inbound rules of the security group of your instance like this:

[image]

Change the port number 21 to your own and add your IP address.

Comment: Thanks Mahdi. inbound rules are fine. As i search and find on google there may be some Active or Passive FTP mode issue. I am not sure about because AWS EC2 use only Passive mode.